SAML request through Google - This account cannot be accessed because we could not parse the login request
I have a problem making a SAML request work.
App context:
The app allows connecting to other accounts of the same Google Workspace domain via a simple login page. It's written in Python3 using Flask.
On Google Workspaces, third party SAML configuration is setup to redirect login requests to one of the app's routes, which processes the SAML request.
What I'm doing with the code:

redirecting the user on login form submit to https://www.google.com/a/{domain_name}/ServiceLogin2?continue=https://mail.google.com/a/{domain_name}
getting the SAML Request and Relay State from the response to this redirection
decoding and extracting the XML Id of the SAML request
creating a SAML Response as follow :

<samlp:Response 
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
    ID="{response_id}" 
    Version="2.0" 
    IssueInstant="{issue_instant}" 
    Destination="{acs_url}" 
    InResponseTo="{in_response_to}">
    <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">{issuer}</Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion 
        xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
        ID="{assertion_id}" 
        IssueInstant="{issue_instant}" 
        Version="2.0">
        <Issuer>{issuer}</Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID 
                Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">{username}</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation 
                Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData 
                    InResponseTo="{in_response_to}" 
                    NotOnOrAfter="{not_on_or_after}" 
                    Recipient="{acs_url}"/>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions 
            NotBefore="{not_before}" 
            NotOnOrAfter="{not_on_or_after}">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>{acs_url}</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement 
            AuthnInstant="{authn_instant}" 
            SessionIndex="{assertion_id}">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
                    urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
                </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>


filling it with the required data
signing it with signxml

root = etree.fromstring(unsigned_saml)
signer = XMLSigner(method=methods.enveloped, c14n_algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#')
    
signed_root = signer.sign(root, key=private_key, cert=certificate)

verified_data = XMLVerifier().verify(signed_root, ca_pem_file='./rsa-cert.pem')
print(verified_data.signed_xml)

# Output the signed SAML Assertion
signed_saml_assertion = etree.tostring(signed_root, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8')
return signed_saml_assertion


encoding the signed saml assertion

b64_encoded_response = base64.b64encode(signed.encode('utf-8')).decode("utf-8")


send a post request to my ACS url containing :

values = {'SAMLResponse' : b64_encoded_response,
                  'RelayState' : relay_state}

response = requests.post(url, data=values)

With these actions I get redirected to a Google error page saying Google Workspace - This account cannot be accessed because we could not parse the login request.
My x509 certificate is still valid and my private key as well.
